# Using a substring of a return value in a subsequent request

Tags: paw-app

I'm attempting to construct a series of Paw calls using the variables feature.  I have one situation I'm unable to solve.

At authentication into the server I'm using, I get a JSON response, with one value that looks like this:

endpoint = "https://sub.something.com/thingone/thingtwo.php?token=sometoken&id=blahblah"

The endpoint portion "https://sub.something.com/" is then used as the base for subsequent calls, where a call might be "GET https://sub.something.com/data?id=123".

I don't want to hardcode the endpoint in Paw, as the endpoint will vary based on factors I can't predict at my end.

Is there a way to do basic string processing like this either in Paw, or by calling out to a shell script and using the return value of said script as a Paw variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's doable using that [RegExp Match](https://paw.cloud/extensions/RegExMatch) dynamic value extension. Click on that previous link and hit **Install Extension**.

Type "Regexp" in the field you expect this value to be used. Pick **Regexp Match** from the completion results:

[image]

Then enter a regexp that matches your need, `https?://[^/]+/?` should be good:

[image]

I've put your example string in the screenshot above to show that it works, but you can instead put a "pointer" (**Response Dynamic Value**) to the response you want:

[image]

In the choices, pick **Response Parsed Body** if you want to parse a JSON or XML from the reponse. If the string is simply in plain text in the response body, pick **Response Raw Body**.

Once these steps are completed, you've got a working "Pointer" + "Parser" to the response that extract the part of the string you need. You can do the same operation with another regex for the `token`…

Tip: these dynamic value tokens can be selected like text and copy/pasted (Cmd+C/Cmd+V) :-)